# Could not understand Struct initialization

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I came across difficult struct initialization.

```
    static struct option long_options[] =
    {
            /* These options set a flag. */
            {"res",    required_argument, NULL, 'r'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
    };
```

Could anybody explain the struct initialization?
I only know Structs like:

```
struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
};
```

Please somebody explain.

Comment: There is a `struct option` somewhere else in the program. The code creates a  `static` array of type `struct option` and initializes the things in it.

Comment: It's not a struct declaration, but a variable declaration.

Comment: @user4098326 and initialization, i.e. a definition.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: Thanks for comments. It is c file. And I do know it is declared somewhere else. I could not find the source file for its declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C and C++ are different languages. The meaning of some of the above depends on whether the language under consideration is C or C++.

The program must contain a declaration of `struct option` in a part of the code which you are not showing us. The statement:

```
static struct option long_options[] =
    {
            /* These options set a flag. */
            {"res",    required_argument, NULL, 'r'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
    };
```

sets an array of such options. Presumably, `{0, 0, 0, 0}` marks the end of the options array. It is known as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

The first element of the `long_options` array of `struct options` has its elements set to `"res"`, `required_argument`, `NULL`, and `'r'`, respectively.

From the initialization, one can deduce that the elements of a `struct option` are

- a `const char *`
- whatever the type of `required_argument` is. It is probably either an `int` or `enum`, or possibly, even a `bool`
- Some kind of pointer
- an `int` (if this is C) or `char` (if this is C++)

Comment: The end of ... means, a sentinel.

Answer (score 4):

A `struct` can have any number and type of variables, even other `struct`s and structure pointers.

Also keep in mind, your code does not show any *structure declaration*. The declaration of the structure is present elsewhere. This is a definition (and initialization) of a `static` array variable named `long_options` of type `struct option`.

Seeing the deifinition, we can *guess*, your `struct` definition *may* look like

```
struct option{

  char * a;
  <type of required_argument> b;
  void * c;
  char d;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a strcture declaration.This is definition of *static array of structures* of type `struct option`.

You need to find *declaration* of `struct option` somewhere else in your program.